# Error when usig back button from Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an activity say A,that takes extras  when started. The problem is when is hit the back button on another activity say B using **setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);** i get an error. The error is obviously due to no extras being send from B. How do i send extras from B to A when using the back button using  **setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);**

Activity A starts like this from say the main Activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_subscreen);
     Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    titleTask = extras.getString(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_TITLE);
    titleid = extras.getLong(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ROWID);
    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle(titleTask);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

Log error is as follows when pressed back button from B

```
04-26 12:39:54.355: E/AndroidRuntime(15573): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 

ComponentInfo{com.group.RedPanda.FinalProject/com.group.RedPanda.FinalProject.SubScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-26 12:39:54.355: E/AndroidRuntime(15573):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
04-26 12:39:54.355: E/AndroidRuntime(15573):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-26 12:39:54.355: E/AndroidRuntime(15573):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-26 12:39:54.355: E/AndroidRuntime(15573):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-26 12:39:54.355: E/AndroidRuntime(15573):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-26 12:39:54.355: E/AndroidRuntime(15573):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-26 12:39:54.355: E/AndroidRuntime(15573):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-26 12:39:54.355: E/AndroidRuntime(15573):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-26 12:39:54.355: E/AndroidRuntime(15573):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-26 12:39:54.355: E/AndroidRuntime(15573):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
04-26 12:39:54.355: E/AndroidRuntime(15573):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-26 12:39:54.355: E/AndroidRuntime(15573):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-26 12:39:54.355: E/AndroidRuntime(15573): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-26 12:39:54.355: E/AndroidRuntime(15573):    at com.group.RedPanda.FinalProject.SubScreen.onCreate(SubScreen.java:29)
04-26 12:39:54.355: E/AndroidRuntime(15573):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-26 12:39:54.355: E/AndroidRuntime(15573):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

Comment: It doesn't sound like you want to actually send extras from B to A. Are you just trying to prevent the crash? There is a high chance you are getting a `NullPointerException` inside your `onResume()` method of Activity A, so you should probably just do a null check, or read from the "extras" in the onCreate method. Can you please post your Activity A code? As well as the LogCat Exception?

Comment: yes im getting a null pointer exception

Comment: Weird, your onCreate method shouldn't be getting called again. How are transitioning to Acitivity B from Activity A? Or from A to B?

Comment: im using an actionbar which consist of the Up navigation button , which i called using setDisplayHomeEnables(true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..What you really want to be doing is something along the lines of this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
      Intent homeIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
      homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
      startActivity(homeIntent);
    }
  return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem));
}
```

Which will take you to the parent activity, rather than just go through the back stack. I've also added the Intent.Flag to clear the back stack, it's a useful one to have when going to a home activity and can stop the back stack getting in a muddle when your users are using the 'Up' button

Comment: is id.home a keyword ?? should i still use setDisplayHomeEnables(true)

Comment: ya.. when u specify android.r.id...u will getsome types .select home and work with that

Comment: another thing what is Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP?

Comment: like finish method. it will remove intent